# Does Prism for Xamarin Forms support native MacOS applications (I.e. Xamarin.Forms.Mac)?

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, prism

Prism for Xamarin Forms does support iOS applications, but, as far as I can tell, does not yet support applications for the Mac itself. Two years ago Prism logged this as an issue, but shortly afterward closed it with the comment "Done". If such support does exist, where can I find it documented? If it does not, does the Prism team still expect to add it?

Unable to find any documentation in Prism Library of support for Xamarin.Forms.MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

From [this blog](https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/07/19/prism-7-0-for-xamarin-forms-sneak-peek) post of one of the Prism developers:

> Whats New Since 6.3 You may be thinking that NetStandard is great and
>   all but that isn't really new. As part of Prism updating to Xamarin
>   Forms 2.3.5, you will now have full support for working with Prism on
>   macOS applications.

So technically it should work.